# How to generate nodes and links from data extracted from a SQLite db table using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Digital Forensic project I am completing in which I am required to visualise a user's activity in order to establish links.  I have extracted all the data and stored it in a SQLite database but I have a list of keywords that I need to run against all the tables in the db.

The purpose of this is to determine which rows contain the keyword so that I can establish a link between these rows and eventually visualize these links using D3.js

For example, one row might contain information from places.sqlite that includes the keyword 'smiley.jpg' and another row might contain information from C:/Users/xxxx/Downloads/ that includes the same keyword.  I want to be able to link these two rows in a json file but also show information such as filename, create_time, access_time etc for each node.  FYI, my data is stored in separate tables like firefox_downloads, form_history, image_files, skype_transfers etc.

So, in summary my question is **how do I run this list of keywords against all tables and output nodes for all rows and links for those that contain the same keyword?**

I hope I have provided enough info but feel free to ask questions!

Thanks...

Comment: Please take a few moments and try to read the huddled mass of test you posted.  If you want others to help you, take the time to format it in a partially readable format.  Think of it like code, written once, but read dozens of times.

Comment: hehehe, just what I was thinking Joe - I edited it for readability. (I see this needs to be approved now)

Comment: Sorry! Will try and make it more readable!